# Save user settings using user default swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swift5

I'm working on an application where users can view terms and like or dislike terms.

I'm stack on saving user settings from the table view using user default. I want to save when users click the like or dislike buttons, and when they run the app again the button stays filled

I have a table view cell that contains an outlet for the button and action

```
import UIKit
class TerminologistTVCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var btnLike: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnDislike: UIButton!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    lconfigureUI()
    dconfigureUI()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


func lconfigureUI(){
    let thumbsdown = UIImage(systemName: "hand.thumbsdown")
    let thumbsdownfilled = UIImage(systemName: "hand.thumbsdown.fill")
    btnDislike.setImage(thumbsdown, for: .normal)
    btnDislike.setImage(thumbsdownfilled, for: .selected)
}
func dconfigureUI(){
    let thumbsup = UIImage(systemName: "hand.thumbsup")
    let thumbsupfilled = UIImage(systemName: "hand.thumbsup.fill")
    btnLike.setImage(thumbsup, for: .normal)
    btnLike.setImage(thumbsupfilled, for: .selected)
}

@IBAction func btnLike(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected.toggle()
    if (sender.isSelected){
        btnDislike.isSelected = false
    }else{
        btnDislike.isSelected = false
    }
}

@IBAction func btnDislike(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected.toggle()
    if (sender.isSelected){
        btnLike.isSelected = false
    }else{
        btnLike.isSelected = false
    }
}}
```

And the ViewController to view the terms and save settings. I tried to save the setting in cellForRow it worked, but when I clicked on the button, it saved for all cells(the button is filled in all cells), not for a cell that I pressed. I want to save for pressed cell

```
class TerminologistVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var termaArray = MDTerms()
let termName = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return termaArray.arabicTerm.count
}

let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let btnLikePressed = "Likepressed"
let btnDisLikePressed = "DisLikepressed"

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TerminologistTVCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.termaArray.arabicTerm[indexPath.row]

    
    cell.btnLike.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btnLike.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likeTerm(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    cell.btnDislike.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btnDislike.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dislikeTerm(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    if userDefaults.bool(forKey: btnLikePressed){
        cell.btnLike.isSelected = true
    }else{
        cell.btnLike.isSelected = false
    }
    
    if userDefaults.bool(forKey: btnDisLikePressed){
        cell.btnDislike.isSelected = true
    }else{
        cell.btnDislike.isSelected = false
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

@objc
func likeTerm(sender: UIButton){
    print("cell index = \(sender.tag)")
    
    if sender.isSelected{
        userDefaults.set(true, forKey: btnLikePressed)
    }else{
        userDefaults.set(false, forKey: btnLikePressed)
    }
}

@objc
func dislikeTerm(sender: UIButton){
    print("cell index = \(sender.tag)")
    if sender.isSelected{
        userDefaults.set(true, forKey: btnDisLikePressed)
    }else{
        userDefaults.set(false, forKey: btnDisLikePressed)
    }
}
```

My application looks like
[ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDNmW.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You are using only two keys in UserDefault which are btnDisLikePressed and btnLikePressed, and clearly you will always get the same values for all cells with all terms. Instead use the termaArray.arabicTerm[indexPath.row] (or in your case cell.textLabel?.text) as the key in UserDefaults.